# Basic Authentication with Firefox in Selenium and Nightwatch.js

Tags: selenium, firefox, basic-authentication, nightwatch.js, selenium-firefoxdriver

I use Nightwatch-Cucumber based on Nightwatch.js. Nightwatch.js is a NodeJS framework based on Selenium.

Currently I'm looking for a smart and simple solution to handle with Basic Authentication, especially with the Firefox. In Chrome I can do the Basic Auth via URL, like:

```
https://user:password@mydomain.com
```

But in Firefox, I get an anti-phishing dialogue box. I tried it manually on `about:config` in Firefox with the new entry:

```
network.http.phishy-userpass-length=255
```

But without success.

At [How to Perform Basic Authentication for FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver & IEdriver in Selenium WebDriver?](https://web.archive.org/web/20171112010024/http://seleniumwebdrivertrainings.com/how-to-perform-basic-authentication-for-firefoxdriver-chromedriver-iedriver-in-selenium-webdriver/), a lot of different solutions were named. But no solution is a smart one.

Maybe is it possible to send a Basic Auth header via Selenium? Or is there any other solution to realize such a Basic Auth, especially in Firefox. A generic solution for every browser/driver will be the smartest solution.

Comment: I tested "http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth" and it worked as expected with the Firefox 54 / geckodriver v0.18.0 with the default settings. I don't see the anti-phishing dialogue box you are talking about. You might want to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You're right. This is a change in geckodriver 0.17.0 (Increasing the length of the network.http.phishy-userpass-length preference will cause Firefox to not prompt when navigating to a website with a username or password in the URL).